# How do I change VCInstallDir location in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've been using VS 2013 for a while and now I have installed VS 2012 due to a project requirement. I'm using Qt, with this project, and there seems to be a problem where Qt can't find stddef.h. When investigating into the problem I noticed that the problem comes from VCInstallDir pointing to the wrong location (It points E:\Program Files(x86)\Visual Studio.... while the actual install is at C:\Program Files(x86)\Visual Studio). What I did was I found all entries in the registry that points to the E:\path\to\VS and converted them to C:\path\to\VS. Now, I restart Windows and create a Qt project again and still VCInstallDir points to the wrong location. I can't figure out where VS 2012 is reading this value from. Could someone kindly point out as to how I can override this value?

Comment: As I understood, in VS 2012 environment options were moved from General VS options to each solution options. Qt developers did not notise that and now Qt is looking for that option in old place. But how to fix this have no idea(((
I need that for windeployqt